# CS0103: The name ' ' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, calculator

I program a  little BMI calculator atm. I coded the basic stuff, which I can work with. I have the problem that my var BMIformula doesnt exist in the context (heading).

Here is my current code:

```
        BMIformula = 0;


        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie Körpergewicht ein: ");
            int bodyWeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie Ihre Körpergröße in cm ein: ");
            int bodyHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            // Console.WriteLine(bodyWeight.ToString(), bodyHeight.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Ihre Eingaben: Körpergewicht: {0}    Körpergröße: {1}", bodyWeight, bodyHeight);

           //  Console.WriteLine("Der BMI beträgt: {0}");

            Console.ReadLine();

        BMIformula = bodyWeight / bodyHeight * bodyHeight;
        BMIformula.ToString();




        if (BMIformula <= 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du bist im Untergewicht!");
        }
        else if (BMIformula >= 20 && BMIformula <= 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du bist im Normalgewicht");
        }
        else if (BMIformula >= 25 && BMIformula <= 30)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du bist Übergewichtig");
        }
        else if (BMIformula >= 30 && BMIformula <= 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du hast Adipositas");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du hast Massive Adipositas");
        }
```

Comment: You have to declare a variable `BMIformula` before you can use it. You have to write something like `float BMIformula;` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your var BMIformula.

```cs
var BMIformula = 0;
```

or

```
float BMIformula = 0;
```